# Adding content to Facebook feed dialog from Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

In my android app, I want users to "share" my app in their wall, so I want them to post a predefined content status on their wall.

How can I customize the wall status? (I want to add my app icon and some flare text).

Comment: That can also be done without the Facebook SDK, via Share url. You definitely want the SDK?

Comment: I want the easiest way possible. :)

Comment: Ok, with the sharer url is the easiest way then, see sample below.

Comment: I have the same problem. Nothing helps. Maybe wait FB SDK to add a new param "message" or "content".

Answer (score 5):

Download the Facebook SDK and import it in your project. Then use the following code to Authorize:

```
    public void sendtoFacebook(){
        facebookClient = new Facebook("<Your_APP_ID");
        facebookClient.authorize(<Current_class>.this, new AuthorizeListener());
    }
```

Now you have to add the following methodes:

```
class AuthorizeListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "<Message_you_want_to_send>");// the message to post to the wall
            facebookClient.dialog(<Current_class>.this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);// "stream.publish" is an API call
    }
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
}
```

Your Application name and Icon will automatically be added :)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want. this one puts text in the text box. I want to give the user opportunity to add text on top of the predefined content. When you share a video from YouTube, there is a dialog the pops up, an empty textbox for you to add status, and below a YouTube content (in this example, an embedded video and text). this is the experience I want my users to have.

Comment: The code i posted is just a simple post to a wall. If you look through the SDK at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk you'll see there are plenty more options, including the ones you want.

Comment: Actually the documentation in this page is pretty minimal (i.e. there is no list of optional parameters to add to the bundle). I guess Facebook API (the standard, not android) is assumed.

Comment: `message` field ignored from July 12, 2011. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @jamapag does it replaced by another field? is there a way in the current API to set content to the post?

Comment: @shem from facebook sdk dialog it's not possible, but you can create custom dialog, and send data by requesting to "me/feed".

Answer (score 3):

After learning the Facebook API, I came across this [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post)

so now I know all the options for the bundle parameters.
Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that without the SDK, just via Share URL:

```
public void shareOnFacebook(View v) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://yourdomain/page.html&t=YourMessage");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You just need to put a content page / html somewhere on your server, under the url your provided to the sharer.

If you want that a certain image appears in the shared message, put this in the meta tag of your html page on the server that you're sharing:

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://yourdomain.com/promo/image.png" />
```

See a sample of such promo page with linked image: http://www.modelme.co.uk/promo/amandaharrington

Comment: What if I don't have a server? just a simple native app?

Comment: Then this approach doesn't work. But you can put this anywhere, any freehosting space (i.e. http://sites.google.com/), as long as it's publicly available via browser.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am making a bundle to set content via a facebook dialog using the Facebook SDK

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("app_id", "xxxxxxx");
        parameters.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myappistasty");
        parameters.putString("name", "This is the name of the link set in app.");
        parameters.putString("caption", "This is Text that is specified in bt the aoo");
        parameters.putString("picture", "www.urltoimage.com);
facebook.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {
etc...
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ 
this is the link that explained all to me, although none of it is in java the table gives you a good idea.